# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined ajax async

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have code

```
  $.ajax('@Url.Action("Surface", "Data")', { async: true, data: { side: i, StartCountForSurface: StartCountForSurface, EndCountForSurface: EndCountForSurface, IsEdit: "true" } })
        .success(function(e) {

            $("#InsertPartial" + i + "").before(e);
            CalculationAS();
            ////отключение валидации

        }).error(function(e) {
            alert(e);
        });
```

when i set async: false,error occurs  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined in Query Validation Plugin

**Update**

javascript code

```
   $("[identificationforcountside]").each(function(ind, element) {
        $(element)[0].value = ArrayOfSides[ind].length;
        AddSurface(ind+1);    <---ajax is here

    });
```

Comment: Can you put the code of the action function (Surface) on the (Data) controller?

Comment: I have seen this error before when you have nested forms in the html - have you checked for such an anomaly in the generated html ?